# Why Babel does not convert a const to an unwritable property in a object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

For studying purposes I'm testing es6 features and using babel to compile it to es5. Now I made a small example where I added a const to a file, and made babel compile it, then I went to check the result and I saw that it simply compiled it to a normal var which, of course, is writable.

For completeness' sake, here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": ["latest"]
}
```

Here is my es6 file:

```
const SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT = 'AbC123';
console.log(SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT);
```

And here is the output after running babel on it:

```
'use strict';

var SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT = 'AbC123';
console.log(SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT);
```

Babel's Try it Out online feature, [gives the same result](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=const%20SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT%20%3D%20'AbC123'%3B%0Aconsole.log(SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT)%3B).

Comment: Babel protects the `const` during compilation and doesn't allow re-declaration. It will yell at you if you try and won't compile the input. Since every attempt at re-declaration will result in an error you shouldn't be able to compile code that redeclares constants.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue yeah, edited the comment. The `SOME_WEIRD_CONSTANT;` in outpt was the result of live compilation in Babel REPL which allowed me to type this far then has thorwn an error.

Comment: Ups, looks like I deleted @CodingIntrigue's comment. Anyway, what he said is true, it throws an error.

Comment: Well, there **are** no consts in ES5, so there's no way for Babel to compile it into some kind of unwritable variable. It can't "convert a const to an unwritable property in a object" because a const does not apply to properties, it applies to variables. What ES5 would you suggest it try to compile it into?

Comment: @torazaburo take a [look here](http://es6-features.org/#Constants). But, as per the comment this "only in global context", and I guess that's why babel doesn't use it.